# Update controller from the view

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind a variable to get the value of the choice of the user (selected in my form) and print it in my HTML (into verifying it works).

Here comes my project: <kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/639gOTY1aDwJU8l65inZ?p=preview)**</kbd>

This method works, but the value is not putted in the controller `<div>{{sel.selectedRequest.site.name}}</div>`

I want this method to work 
`<div ng-bind="sel.texte"></div>`. Maybe it is `<div ng-bind="sel.vm.texte"></div>`?

I remember of something like `console.log(blabla)` but I think it is useless.

I succeed to do it with the system of "$scope" but I have erased this program and I can’t remember what I have written down :S

Comment: what exactly are you trying to show in `ng-bind="sel.texte"`, whole object ??

Comment: I try to display A if you choose A, B if you choose B and nothing if you choose nothing.

Comment: but your `sel.selectedRequest.site.name` is showing exactly this

Comment: Yes but the value is not put in a variable of my controller. I want to show the result only to verify what contains these expressions. But I will do something else with the variable which contains the value.

Comment: @Carapatte you can directly use `$scope.sel.selectedRequest.site.name` from your controller. `ng-model` will work for you :)

Comment: Nope, I can’t write $scope.sel.selectedRequest.site.name either vm.sel.selectedRequest.site.name or my program will bug :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$scope object, as its names says, it's an object on which you should store all other objects you will use on "view" (on your case, html file). As Angular has data binding, it's enough with change dinamicaly any value on $scope and change will be reflexed on your view (html file).

So, here you have a cleaner version of your code use $scope object (and the name of the selected site is displayed):

***index.html***

```
<html ng-app="kibana.controllers">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Log Stack Manager</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="app/services/dashboard.js"></script> -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="lateral_panel" ng-controller="selectCtrl">
            <h1>MENU LSM</h1>
            <h3>Sites: </h3>
            <div class="styled-select">
                <select name="site" ng-model="selectedRequest" ng-options="site.name for site in option" ng-change="update()">
                </select>
            </div>
                <br/><br/>

            <div ng-bind="texte.name"></div>
            <!-- <div>{{sel.selectedRequest.site.name}}</div> -->

                <br/><br/>
            <text1>Chose: </text1>
            <h4>{{selectedRequest.name}}</h4>
            <div ng-show="selectedRequest && selectedRequest.id != 0 " >
                <text2>Contains:</text2>
                <br>
                <h4 ng-repeat="country in selectedRequest.countries">{{country.name}}</h4>
                <br>
                <text3>and:</text3>
                <h4 ng-repeat="server in selectedRequest.servers">{{server.name}}</h4>
            </div>          
        </div>

        <div>
            <form action="index.html">
                <input type="submit" name="OK" value="OK" id="ok">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***script.js***

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
var module = angular.module('kibana.controllers');

        module.controller('selectCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
        //option will be an array wich stores all available options
            $scope.option = [
            {id: 0, name: ""},
            {id: 1, name: "A", 
                countries: [{id: 1, name: "FR" }],
                servers: [{id: 1, name: "1"}, 
                {id: 2, name: "2"},
                {id: 3, name: "3"}]
            },
             {id: 2, name: "B",
                countries: [{id: 1, name: "FR"},{id:2, name: "DE"}],
                servers: [{id: 1, name: "4"}, 
                    {id: 2, name: "5"}, 
                    {id: 3, name: "6"}, 
                    {id: 4, name: "7"}, 
                    {id: 5, name: "8"},
                    {id: 6, name: "9"}]
              }

            ];
      //just store selected option
            $scope.selectedRequest = $scope.option[0];
            $scope.showMessage = true;

      //we store on texte the selected option
            $scope.update = function () {
                $scope.texte = $scope.selectedRequest;
            }

            // vm.selectedRequest = dashboard;

        });


})(angular);
```

Comment: So you are saying that the key-word "this" cannot do the work? Because, in this article https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide it is depreciated to use "$scope".

Comment: No, I have never seen that recomendattion, but it is a good tip ;-)

Comment: I have change all my _vm_ in _$scope_ but my browser show me [object Object]

Comment: Change that line for `<div ng-bind="texte.name"></div>`

Comment: Nope, nothing have changed…

Comment: Could you change it on the plnker application you shared at the beggining? http://plnkr.co/edit/639gOTY1aDwJU8l65inZ?p=preview I will check what is wrong

Comment: Finally, it was text.site.name : plnkr.co/edit/639gOTY1aDwJU8l65inZ?p=preview. I think it woks now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Beside what was mentioned by @Javier Plá Herrero, there are a few other things that can be improved in your code:

1- `{id: 0, name: ""},` is obsolet because by default select will already have an empty option displayed

2- `$scope.selectedRequest = $scope.option[0];` is also obsolet as long as empty option created by angularjs will by default be selected

3 - update function can be doen directly in html using `ng-change="texte =selectedRequest"`

Comment: Ok for the point one and two, but for the last, would it be a variable stocked in my controller which will get it ?

Comment: @Carapatte yes, the variable `texte` mentioned in `ng-change`  can be accesed in controller via `$scope.texte`

Comment: Excuse me, but I don’t really understand. I have to write `$scope.texte = texte;` ?

Comment: No. You just change `ng-change="update()"` into `ng-change="texte =selectedRequest"`, remove the update function from controller and it will work as you expect, given that you also applied the changes mentioned by  @Javier Plá Herrero.

Comment: About to have a variable containing the value of _texte_ and which is stocked in my controller. Does the _$scope.texte_ will contain the value of _texte_?

Comment: yes, these are the same object. Just if you are in html and want to access an object from scope you don't write `$scope.texte` but only `texte`, in controller however you have to write `$scope.texte` to access this object. But this is one single object.

Comment: Ok :) I remember it now. Thanks